# For each natural number $n \geq 1$, let $a_n = \frac{n}{10^[\log_{10}n]}$ , where $[x]$ = smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

For each natural number $n \geq 1$, let $a_n = \frac{n}{10^{[\log_{10}n]}}$ , where $[x]$ = smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$. Which of the following statements are true?

1. $\liminf a_n = 0$
2. $\liminf a_n$ does not exist
3. $\liminf a_n = 0.15$
4. $\limsup a_n = 1$

If I take $n = {10}^n$ then $a_n = \frac{{10}^n}{10^{[\log_{10}{10}^n]}} = 1$,   $\forall n \in \Bbb N$ So $\limsup a_n = 1$ but I am not sure about it. I have no information how discard other options.

Comment: You missed the braces around the exponent of $10$ in the title.  You got them in the body.

Comment: Please give me some hints

Comment: You have shown that $a_n=1$ infinitely often.  Now ask yourself what is $a_n$ for other values of $n$, like $10^k-1$.  You should not use $n$ as the exponent as $n=10^n$ is false.